# Помогите конвертировать эти функции в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Нужна помощь в переводе этих формул в JavaScript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас что-то не получается?

Comment: интересное слово "конвертировать"

Comment: Подсказка: используйте функции `Math.asin`, `Math.acos`,  `Math.tan`, и `Math.abs`.

Comment: Не забудь проверять входные данные, потому что  arcsin и arccos, если я еще что-то помню со школы, не от всякого числа можно вычислить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function onFist(){
   var f;
   var x=document.getElementById("x").value*1;
   var b=document.getElementById("b").value*1;
   var a=document.getElementById("a").value*1;
   f=Math.asin(Math.pow(x,2)+b)-((Math.pow(x,3)*Math.pow(Math.tan(b-a),2))/(Math.abs(a*b-Math.pow(x,2))));  
   document.write((f).toFixed(5)+"<br>");
   document.write('<input type="text" id="x">'); 
   document.write('<input type="text" id="b">');
   document.write('<input type="text" id="a">');
   document.write('<input type="submit" onClick="onSecond()"><br>');
  }
  function onSecond(){
   var f;
   var x=document.getElementById("x").value*1;
   var b=document.getElementById("b").value*1;
   var a=document.getElementById("a").value*1;
   f=(Math.pow(Math.asin(x-b),3))/(Math.acos(Math.pow(a-x,2)));
   document.write((f).toFixed(5));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function F1(x, a, b) {
  return (Math.asin(Math.pow(x, 2) + b) - ((Math.pow(x, 3) * Math.pow(Math.tan(b - a), 2)) / (Math.abs(a * b - Math.pow(x, 2)))));
}

function F2(x, a, b) {
  return ((Math.pow(Math.asin(x - b), 3)) / (Math.acos(Math.pow(a - x, 2))));
}
```